# AJAX/JS/PHP: How to replace text in file sent to PHP file, and pass successful attribute?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have this button by ID of genPDF, which if clicked has this function:

```
$('#genPDF').click(function () {

    var str = "headingText=" + jQuery("#headingText").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'indexpdf.php',
        data: str,
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'post',
        success: function () {
            console.log("Success!");
        }
    });
})
```

It's supposed to take the text from input "headingText" and send to the php file indexpdf.php.

Then here's my indexpdf.php:

```
<?
$headingText = trim(isset($_POST['headingText']) ? $_POST['headingText'] : '');

$initialpdf = file_get_contents('file_html.php');

$initialpdf = str_replace(array(
        '%headingText%'
    ), array (
        $headingText,
    ), $initialpdf);

file_put_contents($fp, $initialpdf);
?>
```

This file is supposed to decalre the headingtext variable from the previous page, and replace each "%headingText%" in file_html.php, then save this html/php file as "file_html2.php"

The problems are, I don't think I'm saving the finalized php file right, and for some reason, while passing the "str" into the ajax php call, it doesn't succeed. If I get rid of the line, "data: str,", it succeeds.

How can I pass in these string variables, replace them in the php file, and save that file as a different file succesfully? What's wrong here?

Comment: What is the error ? "*...while passing the "str" into the ajax php call, it doesn't succeed..*" What Problem you are facing ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar it never makes it to the console.log call, and there are no errors mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**An Alternative Way**

```
<script>
$('#genPDF').click(function () {
  var str = $("#headingText").val();
  $.ajax({url:"indexpdf.php?headingText="+str,cache:false,success:function(result){
        console.log("Success!");
  }});
})
</script>
```

Use `_GET`

```
<?
$headingText = trim(isset($_GET['headingText']) ? $_GET['headingText'] : '');

$initialpdf = file_get_contents('file_html.php');

$initialpdf = str_replace(array(
        '%headingText%'
    ), array (
        $headingText,
    ), $initialpdf);

$initialpdf->saveHTMLFile("file_html2.php");
?>
```

Comment: I tried your approach and the only thing wrong is that  "file_html2.php" is neither being created, nor gets contents placed inside of it. See my revised code..

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass an object to data. For this, replace:

```
data: str
```

with:

```
data: { headingText: jQuery("#headingText").val() },
```

This should pass the value correctly

Comment: This doesn't work. the ajax call doesn't get to the console call.

Answer (score 1):

**First Part**
You are forcing ajax request to json type and trying to post data as string thats why its not working, try posting your `headingText` in JSON format i.e.

```
data: {headingText: jQuery("#headingText").val()}
```

this will make sure you receive data in PHP

**Second Part**

After making all the changes you can use alternate function to `file_get_contents` to store file once manipulation is done i.e. `file_put_contents`
Use it like

```
$initialpdf = file_get_contents('file_html.php');

$initialpdf = str_replace(array(
        '%headingText%'
    ), array (
        $headingText,
    ), $initialpdf);

file_put_contents("file_html2.php", $initialpdf);
```

this should address your both issues.

Comment: I tried your approach and the only thing wrong is that  "file_html2.php" is neither being created, nor gets contents placed inside of it.

Comment: what does the error logs say? can you try these steps $handle = fopen("file_html2.php", 'w'); fwrite($handle, $initialpdf); fclose($handle);

Answer (score -1):

Try sending it as a json object instead of a string.

```
str = {headingText:'blabla'}
```

Comment: This does not work because you have made a mistake in your code. You need to set method : post
Not type:post.
No need to send it in url which is not considered safe unless data is not sensitive.